# How can I calculate $\mathbb Z[x]/x^2 \times \mathbb Z[y]/y^2 \times \mathbb Z[z]/z^2$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, polynomial-rings

I am guessing that $\mathbb Z[x]/x^2 \times \mathbb Z[y]/y^2 \times \mathbb Z[z]/z^2 = \mathbb Z[x,y,z]/(x^2, y^2, z^2, xy, yz, xz)$ but I do not have an educated justification for this if it is true. If it is wrong, could someone explain to me the correct solution?

Comment: Hint: How many integers do you have to specify to give a generic element of the first ring? How about for the second ring? Are the underlying additive groups isomorphic?

Comment: I do not understand your hint, could you please explain more?

Comment: What I'm saying is, forget about multiplication and just look at the underlying additive abelian groups. Are these isomorphic as abelian groups? If not, then they certainly can't be isomorphic as rings. As a starting point, observe that $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2)$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}^2$ as an abelian group.

Comment: I think so. Ok, so if I changed my symbol to direct sum instead of product will my isomorphism be correct? @DanielHast

Comment: @Brain Whenever you're dealing with finitely many rings/groups, as you are here, there's no meaningful distinction between direct products and direct sums (i.e. they're at least isomorphic if not identical).  That is, changing to direct sum ultimately changes nothing about your problem, so it certainly cannot fix it.

Comment: @BrianMoehring Ok so there is no way to write it as $\mathbb Z[x,y,z]$ moded by anything, am I correct? it is just what it is no simplification after that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The suggested isomorphism is wrong. The ring $$\mathbb Z[x,y,z]/(x^2, y^2, z^2, xy, yz, xz)$$ has only two idempotents, while the other ring has eight idempotents.

If $f(f-1)\in (x^2, y^2, z^2, xy, yz, xz)$, then $f(0)(f(0)-1)=0$. Suppose $f(0)=0$. It follows that $f\in(x,y,z)$. Then $f^2\in (x^2, y^2, z^2, xy, yz, xz)$, so $f\in(x^2, y^2, z^2, xy, yz, xz)$.

Comment: So what is the correct isomorphism?

Comment: or maybe we have $\mathbb Z[x]/x^2 \times \mathbb Z[y]/y^2 \times \mathbb Z[z]/z^2 = \mathbb Z[x,y,z]/(x^2, y^2, z^2, xy, yx, zy, yz, xz, zx)$

Comment: As far as I know $xy=yx$.

Comment: Oh I see, is that because we have a multiplication in $\mathbb Z$?

Comment: What other ring you are speaking about?

Comment: So the correct answer is \mathbb Z[x,y,z]/(x^2, y^2, z^2, xy, yz, xz)$ as I wrote it in my question above ..... am I correct?

Comment: As far as I can see there are two rings in your question, and you claimed that these are isomorphic. Well, they aren't!

Comment: But I can understand what you actually want: you want to write $\mathbb Z[x]/x^2×\mathbb Z[y]/y^2×\mathbb Z[z]/z^2$ as a quotient of $\mathbb Z[x,y,z]$. I'm not sure if this is possible.